# String manipulation - GA

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I'm having trouble (all sorts of different ones), with my mutation function for an Genetic algorithm. I manipulate strings as DNA, which come from `Integer.toString(Float.floatToIntBits(value))`.  Everything cross-over nicely, and repopulates, so now its time for some nasty mutations. And now i have a problem, this is my mutation function:

```
public void muttate() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int mutationPoint = rand.nextInt(valueString.length()-1);
    //int mutationPoint=valueString.length()-1;
    //System.out.println(mutationPoint);
    if(mutationPoint==0)
        valueString = rand.nextInt(10)
        + valueString.substring(0);
    else if (mutationPoint == 1)
        valueString = valueString.charAt(0)
                + Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(10))
                + valueString.substring(mutationPoint);
    else if (mutationPoint != valueString.length()-1)
        valueString = valueString.substring(0, mutationPoint-1)
                + Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(10))
                + valueString.substring(mutationPoint);
    else
        valueString = valueString.substring(0, mutationPoint - 1)
                + Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(10));
    changeStringtovalue();
    calculateFitnes();
}
```

and as i run it, i see it eats up my DNA (so length is first 9, then after some time is 8 and so long). And it comes from this mutation part, not cross-overs (tested). I think it's some kind of stupid mistake, but i just can't find a clue.

And also, is that kind of mutation even valid for this situation? Maybe I should manipulate bits, after applying masks, to get to certain part of that float.

Comment: are you missing a '+ valueString.substring(mutationPoint);' from the Else block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutate is spelled without the double `tt`. Your code will never mutate the last position because of the way you call random.

The problem is `substring(start, end)` returns a string that does not include the end index character. So you're losing one character. The whole if block is unneeded as well.
If you're trying to mutate, you could write a function like this:

```
public void mutate() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int mutPos = rand.nextInt(valueString.length());
    valueString = valueString.substring(0, mutPos) 
        + rand.nextInt(10) + valueString.substring(mutPos+1);
}
```

Here's some tips:

Given string `"ABC"`.

`substring(1,2)` returns `"B"`, index 1 inclusive to index 2 exclusive.

`substring(0, string.length())` return whole string.

`substring(0)` returns whole string.

`substring(i, i)` returns `""`

Substring also returns `""` if it starts (and ends) at index one past the last character (at `string.length()` index.

This allows you to easily handle corner cases without if sentences as demonstrated in the code I wrote above.

Comment: Thank you, and i will refractor the naming (especaily it has to be in my native language:)). I got cought up in handling all errors, so this is why so manny ifs. and also there is still an error for mutPos= 0, but i can handle that.

Comment: Hm.... should not be an error. For mutPos=0 you should get:
`substring(0,0) + int + substring(1)` which should resolve into `"" + int + all characters but the first one`. The only way this could return an error is if string was null or 0 length.

Comment: Tested it by running it 1000000 times in a loop, no error thrown.

Comment: the error comes from the second part of my question, and as i learned it the hard way, in this representation of a float, changing the 0 position makes it a nonsens.But ofcourse your code is fine, big thanks once again!